# Django select_related query does not return all values to the template

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-1.10

I have 2 models. Characters and CharactersDetails from a django site I'm fooling around with.

CharactersDetails has a foreignkey relationship to Characters

```
class CharactersDetails(models.Model):
    character_link = models.ForeignKey(Characters)
```

In my view, I'm doing this:

```
'character_info': CharactersDetails.objects.select_related('character_link').filter(character_link_id=pk)
```

In my template, I'm only getting back the fields from the CharactersDetails table.

In the manage.py shell, I ran the same query and found it's actually returning the fields from both CharactersDetails and Characters (which is what I want), but when the view gets the context object, it's only showing the items from the CharactersDetails table.

```
(looking_for_guild_env)klainn:~/workspace (master) $ python manage.py shell
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
>>> from players.models import Characters,CharactersDetails
>>> myjunk = CharactersDetails.objects.select_related('character_link').filter(character_link_id=1)
>>> print(myjunk)
<QuerySet [<CharactersDetails: CharactersDetails object>]>
>>> print(myjunk.query)
SELECT "characters_details"."id", "characters_details"."character_link_id", "characters_details"."character_class_id", "characters_details"."character_race_id", "characters_details"."character_level", "characters_details"."character_armory_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_image_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_avatar_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_inset_url", "characters"."id", "characters"."character_owner_id", "characters"."character_name", "characters"."character_realm_id", "characters"."character_faction_id", "characters"."insert_date" FROM "characters_details" INNER JOIN "characters" ON ("characters_details"."character_link_id" = "characters"."id") WHERE "characters_details"."character_link_id" = 1
>>>
```

I take that same query and paste it into the manage.py dbshell:

```
(looking_for_guild_env)klainn:~/workspace (master) $ python manage.py dbshell
sqlite> SELECT "characters_details"."id", "characters_details"."character_link_id", "characters_details"."character_class_id", "characters_details"."character_race_id", "characters_details"."character_level", "characters_details"."character_armory_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_image_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_avatar_url", "characters_details"."character_profile_inset_url", "characters"."id", "characters"."character_owner_id", "characters"."character_name", "characters"."character_realm_id", "characters"."character_faction_id", "characters"."insert_date" FROM "characters_details" INNER JOIN "characters" ON ("characters_details"."character_link_id" = "characters"."id") WHERE "characters_details"."character_link_id" = 1;
1|1|15|7|110|http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/Stormrage/Peppiwyn/simple|stormrage/219/182881755-profilemain.jpg|stormrage/219/182881755-avatar.jpg|stormrage/219/182881755-inset.jpg|1|3|Peppiwyn|192|0|2017-03-20
```

And I get all fields. But the template doesn't get passed the last 6 values. I could see this when I add a .values() to the end of the queryset and then do a:

```
{{ character_info }}
```

in the template I see:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'character_profile_image_url': 'stormrage/219/182881755-profilemain.jpg', 'character_race_id': 7, 'character_level': 110, 'character_profile_avatar_url': 'stormrage/219/182881755-avatar.jpg', 'character_profile_inset_url': 'stormrage/219/182881755-inset.jpg', 'character_armory_url': 'http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/Stormrage/Peppiwyn/simple', 'character_link_id': 1, 'character_class_id': 15}]>
```

Have I done something wrong or is there a special way I should be calling these values from the template?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queryset method `.values()` does not add implicitely the attributes of the foreign keys selected. Here is an [extract of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

> A few subtleties that are worth mentioning:
>
> - If you have a field called foo that is a `ForeignKey`, **the default `values()` call will return a dictionary key called foo_id, since this is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value** (the foo attribute refers to the related model). When you are calling `values()` and passing in field names, you can pass in either foo or foo_id and you will get back the same thing (the dictionary key will match the field name you passed in).

You need to list the fields as `values('character_link__field1', 'character_link__field2'...)` arguments... or just don't use it and process ORM objects, that will use the data retrieved in one query.

With tools like [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar), you can inspect your requests to ensure only one SQL query is made when you are rendering your template.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `select_related('character_link')` doesn't add the attributes to the `character_info` instance, it just fetches the `character_info` from the db at the same time as `character_link`, using an inner join.

In the template, you access the `character_link` instance `{{ character_info.character_link }}`.

If you are using `values()`, you have to explicitly include fields from `character_link`:

```
.values('field1', 'field2', 'character_link__field', ...)
```